# click single cell select entire row datagrid VB6

Tags: datagrid, vb6

Is there a way to select an entire row in a datagridview?

Select not just the single cell, but the whole row to highlight the whole row of a particular record?

Comment: IIRC that's called something like `SelectionMode` in the properties toolwindow (F4).

Comment: there;s no SelectionMode property in VB6 :(

Comment: there's no datagrid in VBA. Are you using VBA? Is it ListView?

Comment: I use Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say you are using VB6 do you mean you are using a DataGrid control? If so, this is something normally handled by setting the RecordSelectors property to true. This causes arrows to the left of the splits to be displayed and allows the user to select an entire row. When the user clicks a recordselector it adds the row to the SelBookmarks collection. If you want to do this for the user for any row / column clicked in you can do it manually by adding code to the DataGrid_RowColChange event.

```
Private Sub DataGrid1_RowColChange(LastRow As Variant, ByVal LastCol As Integer)
    DataGrid1.SelBookmarks.Add DataGrid1.Bookmark
End Sub
```

Here is the MSDN reference for the DataGrid control. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260194(v=vs.60).aspx

Answer (score 1):

In the datagrid control, in order to select an entire row, you should have a `SelectionMode` property which could be set to `SelectionByRow` (or something like that).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like ...

```
Private Sub DataGrid1_Click()
    DataGrid1.SelStartCol = 0
    DataGrid1.SelEndCol = DataGrid1.Columns.Count - 1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Grid1.SelBookmarks.Remove 0 
Grid1.SelBookmarks.Add Grid1.Bookmark
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPZdl.jpg)